# Geometry with a circle from a Romanian contest

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $M$ be a point exterior to a circle $\mathcal{C}(O, r)$. Let us consider the tangents $MA$ and $MB$ to this circle ($A$ and $B$ are on the circle). The parallel lines through $A$ and $B$ to the lines $MB$ and $MA$ intersect the circle the second time in $C$ and $D$, respectively, and the lines $MC$ and $MD$ intersect the circle the second time in $E$ and $F$ respectively. Let $\{Q\}=BF \cap MA$ and $\{P\}=AE\cap MB$. If $x\cdot \overrightarrow{AB} + y \cdot \overrightarrow{AC} + z \cdot \overrightarrow{AQ}+ t \cdot \overrightarrow{MP}=\overrightarrow{0}$, where $x, y, z, t\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$, then it is true that:
a) $2x+z=1$
b) $x+z=0$
c) $\frac{z-t}{y}=\frac{AC}{MP}$
d) $\frac{z+t}{y}=\frac{AC}{PB}$
e) $\frac{z-t}{y}=\frac{4AC}{MB}$.

This question appeared in a Romanian contest for high school students approximately a month ago. I have been trying to solve it for quite a while, but I haven't made much progress. I think that I should write the power of $M$ with respect to our circle because this would give me some relation between those lengths. Another thing that I observed, yet I don't know how to prove, is that $PQ \parallel AB$. This together with Thales' Theorem would give us that $\frac{MP}{PB}=\frac{MQ}{QA}$. Apart from these, I haven't found much more.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, I will add here that the correct answer is c).

Comment: This is such a mess... Not a nice problem. Well, to do something, i would suggest to use a special configuration of points that makes the computation easy in cartesian coordinates. For instance, start with the case when $MAOB$ is a square. Then find all points, and write explicitly the vectors. This will separate the cases where that "true" is really **true** from cases where "true" is false. (At a first glance it seems that the problem is a multiple choice problem, and the sense of *"then is true that"* is in fact *"then which of the following claims are true"*. Did they ask for proofs too?

Comment: @dan_fulea Yeah, it was a multiple choice problem and they didn't ask for the proofs. It really looks messy, I quickly got lost in it and I couldn't exploit my ideas a lot.

Comment: With a coordinate bash, I find $$\begin{align}
4x+z+t+8y\cos^2\theta&=0\\-z+t+8y\cos^2\theta&=0\end{align}$$ where $\theta=\angle MOA$. Subtracting yields $2x+z=0$, which is *almost* option (a). (Could it be a typo? Please? :) Fun fact: $P$ and $Q$ are midpoints of $\overline{MB}$ and $\overline{MA}$.

Comment: @Blue It is not a typo, I checked the official paper again. If it helps anyone, according to the answer sheet (which, of course, doesn't give a solution), the correct answer is c).

Comment: @MathGuy: Ah, well ... I guess that would've been too easy. :)  ... You should note the correct answer in the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked (and may be hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let us prove that $P$ and $Q$ are midpoints of $\overline{MB}$ and $\overline{MA}$.

*Proof* :

Let $$G=AC\cap BF,\quad H=AC\cap BD,\quad I=AC\cap MD$$

Also, let $$AG=a,\quad HI=b,\quad MB=AH=MA=BH=k,\quad BF=t$$

Since $\triangle{GQA}\sim\triangle{BQM}$, we have
$$QA:QM=AG:MB=a:k\implies QA=\frac{ak}{a+k},QM=\frac{k^2}{a+k}$$

Since $\triangle{IDH}\sim\triangle{MDB}$, we have
$$HD:BD=IH:MB=b:k\implies BD=\frac{k^2}{b+k}$$

Since $\triangle{MQF}\sim\triangle{DBF}$, we have
$$QM:BD=QF:BF\implies \frac{k^2}{a+k}:\frac{k^2}{b+k}=QF:t\implies QF=\frac{(b+k)t}{a+k}$$

Since $QA^2=QF\times QB$, we have
$$\bigg(\frac{ak}{a+k}\bigg)^2=\frac{(b+k)t}{a+k}\times\bigg(t+\frac{(b+k)t}{a+k}\bigg)$$
$$\implies t^2=\frac{a^2k^2}{(b+k)(a+b+2k)}\tag1$$

Since $\triangle{DMB}\sim\triangle{BMF}$, we have
$$MD:MB=BD:FB\implies MD:k=\frac{k^2}{b+k}:t\implies MD=\frac{k^3}{t(b+k)}$$

Since $\triangle{FDB}\sim\triangle{FMQ}$, we have
$$DF:MF=BF:QF=t:\frac{(b+k)t}{a+k}\implies MF=\frac{k^3}{t(a+b+2k)}$$

Since $\triangle{DMB}\sim\triangle{BMF}$, we have
$$MB:MD=MF:MB\implies k:\frac{k^3}{t(b+k)}=\frac{k^3}{t(a+b+2k)}:k$$
$$\implies t^2=\frac{k^4}{(b+k)(a+b+2k)}\tag2$$

It follows from $(1)(2)$ that $a=k$, i.e. $AG=MB$ from which $AQ=MQ$ follows.

Similarly, we have $BP=MP$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Let $\vec{AM}=\vec a,\vec{AH}=\vec b$.

Then, we have
$$\begin{align}&x\cdot \overrightarrow{AB} + y \cdot \overrightarrow{AC} + z \cdot \overrightarrow{AQ}+ t \cdot \overrightarrow{MP}=\overrightarrow{0}
\\\\&\implies x(\vec a+\vec b) + y \cdot \frac{AC}{AH}\cdot \vec b + z \cdot \frac 12\vec a+ t\cdot\frac 12\vec b=\overrightarrow{0}
\\\\&\implies \bigg(x+\frac z2\bigg)\vec a+\bigg(x+\frac y2\cdot \frac{AC}{MP}+\frac t2\bigg)\vec b=\vec 0
\\\\&\implies x+\frac z2=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad x+\frac y2\cdot \frac{AC}{MP}+\frac t2=0
\\\\&\implies 2x+z=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{z-t}{y}=\frac{AC}{MP}\end{align}$$

- Suppose that (a) is correct. Then, we have $1=2x+z=0$.
- Suppose that (b) is correct. Then, we have $x=z=0$.
- Suppose that (d) is correct. Then, we have $\frac{z+t}{y}=\frac{z-t}{y}\implies t=0$.
- Suppose that (e) is correct. Then, we have $\frac{z-t}{2y}=\frac{z-t}{y}\implies z=t\implies AC=0$.

Therefore, the only correct option is $\color{red}{\text{(c)}}$.

Comment: Amazing solution, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We can consider the special case where the tangents make a $60^\circ$ angle at $M$. Then $C$ and $D$ coincide, as do $E$ and $F$; we find $P$ and $Q$ to be the midpoints of $\overline{MB}$ and $\overline{MA}$. (The midpoint property happens to be true in all cases.)

[image]

Defining $\vec{p}:=\overrightarrow{MP}$ and $\vec{q}:=\overrightarrow{AQ}$, we clearly have $\overrightarrow{AB}=2(\vec{p}+\vec{q})$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}=2\vec{p}$. Therefore,
$$0 = x\,\overrightarrow{AB} + y\,\overrightarrow{AC} + z\,\overrightarrow{AQ} + t\,\overrightarrow{MP} = (2x+2y+t)\vec{p}+(2x+z)\vec{q}$$
Since $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ are linearly independent, the individual coefficients must vanish. (So, right away, we know that condition (a) doesn't hold.) We can readily deduce
$$\frac{z-t}{y} = 2 = \frac{|AC|}{|MP|}$$
which is condition (c).

Further, we can rule-out the other conditions by considering a particular solution, say, $(x,y,z,t) = (1,1,-2,-4)$ and noting that $|AC|/|PB|=2$ and $|AC|/|MB|=1$.

Assuming[(!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEP1acj29-Y) that at least one condition *always* holds, that condition must be (c). $\square$

---

**Addendum.** Here's a proof of "the midpoint property" (specifically, $P$ is the midpoint of $\overline{MB}$) in general. Let $O$ be the center of the circle.

[image]

- Since $\overline{AC}\parallel\overline{MB}$ (and thus $\overline{AC}\perp\overline{OB}$), we have $\angle AOB=\angle BOC$; let $\theta$ be the common measure.
- Then, inscribed angle $\angle AEC=\frac12(360^\circ-2\theta)$, so that $\angle AEM$ also has measure $\theta$.
- Further, "inscribed" angle $\angle MAC$ (with side $\overline{AM}$ tangent to the circle) *also* has measure $\theta$.

Now, drop a perpendicular from $M$ to the extension of $\overline{AC}$, and let $A'$ be the reflection of $A$ in that perpendicular.

- That perpendicular necessarily passes through the circumcenter $O'$ of $\triangle MAA'$; moreover, since $\overline{MB}\parallel\overline{AA'}$, we have that $\overline{MB}$ is tangent to $\bigcirc O'$ at $M$.
- As $\angle MEA$ and $\angle MA'A$ are necessarily supplementary, $\square MEAA'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. In particular, $E$ lies on $\bigcirc O'$.

We have, then, that $\overleftrightarrow{AE}$ is the [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) of the two circles, and thus necessarily bisects their common tangent segment, $\overline{MB}$, at $P$. $\square$

And ... To show that condition (c) holds in general ... Let's define $s:=r/2$ and $\phi:=\theta/2$ (to avoid fractions).

[image]

Take $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ as before (so that $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is still $2(\vec{p}+\vec{q})$). Note that $|\vec{p}|=|\vec{q}|=s\tan\phi$. Defining $\vec{c}:=\overrightarrow{AC}$, we have $|\vec{c}|=4s\sin2\phi=8s\sin\phi\cos\phi=8s\tan\phi\cos^2\phi$, so that $\vec{c} = 8\vec{p}\,\cos^2\phi$.

Then, the vanishing vector sum condition implies
$$2x+8y\cos^2\phi+t \;=\; 2x+z \;=\; 0$$
so that
$$\frac{z-t}{y}= 8\cos^2\phi = \frac{|\vec{c}|}{|\vec{p}|}=\frac{|AC|}{|MP|}$$
as desired. $\square$

Comment: thank you! I know this may be pretty dumb, but why can we get away with only considering the special case when the tangents make a $60^{\circ}$ angle at $M$?

Comment: @MathGuy: *"why can we get away with only considering the special case [...]?"* ... If a condition *fails* for the special case, then it's a false condition. The special case (and the particular solution thereof) rules-out everything but (c). Unless the contest allows a "none of the above" response, we may safely conclude that (c) is the correct answer. ... That said, it would be more-satisfying to avoid this kind of "meta" argument. My ugly coordinate bash verifies condition (c), but the midpoint property leads me to suspect that an elegant proof may be waiting somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I see. I also thought that you were exploiting this "meta" argument, but there was also a slight chance that there was some reason why this could be done rigorously. Yes, it would be interesting to see a solution that actually proves c) in the general case, but your solution is also really good since it actually solves the given problem (from my experience, some multiple choice questions are really really hard to solve without such "meta" arguments and most likely the proposers expected the students to take advantage of this).